# Extracting non-zero coefficients in glmnet in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet, lasso-regression

I'm doing a lasso logistic regression. I've used cv.glmnet to get the non-zero coefficients. And it seems to work i.e. I do get some non-zero coefficients and the rest go to zero. However, when I use coef function to print all coefficients it gives me a list of all coefficients. Is there a way to extract coefficients and their names that are not zero. 
The code of what I've done is:

```
cv.lasso = cv.glmnet(x_train,y_train, alpha = 0.6, family = "binomial")
coef(cv.lasso, s=cv.lasso$lambda.1se)
```

When I use coef I get following output:

```
4797 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

                  1

(Intercept)   -1.845702

sampleid.10    .       
sampleid.1008  .
```

I want to extract the name and value of non zero coefficients. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very convenient way to do so is the `extract.coef` function of the [`coefplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coefplot/index.html) package.

Here is a simple reproducible example, adapted from the `cv.glmnet` docs:

```
library(glmnet)
library(coefplot)

set.seed(1010)
n=1000;p=100
nzc=trunc(p/10)
x=matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p)
beta=rnorm(nzc)
fx= x[,seq(nzc)] %*% beta
eps=rnorm(n)*5
y=drop(fx+eps)
px=exp(fx)
px=px/(1+px)
ly=rbinom(n=length(px),prob=px,size=1)
set.seed(1011)

# model:
cvob1=cv.glmnet(x,y)
```

Here `x` has 100 variables, V1 to V100; which of them have non-zero coefficients?

```
extract.coef(cvob1)
# result:
                  Value SE Coefficient
(Intercept) -0.11291017 NA (Intercept)
V1          -0.41095526 NA          V1
V2           0.50127803 NA          V2
V4          -0.40319404 NA          V4
V5          -0.42518885 NA          V5
V6           0.42609526 NA          V6
V7           0.41845873 NA          V7
V8          -1.54881117 NA          V8
V9           1.23284876 NA          V9
V10          0.31187777 NA         V10
V14         -0.03085618 NA         V14
V18         -0.15211282 NA         V18
V26          0.19704039 NA         V26
V30         -0.11568702 NA         V30
V31         -0.07108829 NA         V31
V36          0.15282509 NA         V36
V39          0.10250912 NA         V39
V47         -0.02602025 NA         V47
V60          0.04502238 NA         V60
V63         -0.07051392 NA         V63
V68          0.06431373 NA         V68
V75         -0.35798561 NA         V75
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the matrix notation.

```
library(MASS)
library(glmnet)
set.seed(8675309)
### simulate covariates from inepedent normals
xx <- mvrnorm(100, rep(0, 100), diag(1, 100))
### simulate coefficients first 50 from beta second 50 0 => spurious features
my_beta <- c(runif(50, -2, 2), rep(0, 50))
## simulate responses
yy <- rbinom(100, 1, plogis(xx %*% my_beta))

## do your glmnet
reg <- cv.glmnet(x = xx, y = yy, alpha  = 0.5, family = 'binomial')


rownames(coef(reg, s = 'lambda.min'))[coef(reg, s = 'lambda.min')[,1]!= 0] ### returns nonzero coefs
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to get the coefficient values different from zero AND the coefficient names, you can do as such:

```
# I start with your command, and assign to a variable just to make the code more readable
outcome <- coef(cv.lasso, s=cv.lasso$lambda.1se)
outcome[outcome[,1]!=0,]
```