# Error extracting non-zero glmnet coefficients with "which"

Tags: r, glmnet, coefficients, cox

I fitted a cox model with *glmnet* like:

```
fitL <- glmnet(
  X,
  Y,
  family = "cox",
  alpha = 1,
  lambda = cvL$lambda.min, #cvL obteined with cv.glmnet
  standardize = FALSE,
  thresh = thresh
)
```

I obtained:

```
str(coef(fitL) != 0)
Formal class 'lgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:24] 0 76 81 96 125 149 213 266 277 415 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:2] 0 24
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 1000 1
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:1000] "001" "002" "003" "004" ...
  .. ..$ : chr "s0"
  ..@ x       : logi [1:24] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
  ..@ factors : list()
```

I would like to extract the non-zero coefficients (i.e. the selected variables), I used "which" and I had this error:

```
> which (coef (fitL)! = 0)
```

> Error in base :: which (x, arr.ind, useNames,
>   ...): the 'which' argument must be of logical type

I also used `extract.coef` function of the `coefplot` package proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984540/extracting-non-zero-coefficients-in-glmnet-in-r). I had this error:

```
> library (coefplot)
> coefplot :: extract.coef (fitL)
```

> Error in UseMethod (generic = "extract.coef", object = model):    no
>   method for 'extract.coef' applicable for an object of class "c
>   ('coxnet', 'glmnet')"

Answer (score 2):

Use `predict` instead with argument `type="nonzero"`.

Answer (score 1):

The object `(coef(fitL) != 0)` has the class `lgCMatrix`. Try to use `as.vector`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's work: which(as.vector(coef(fitL) != 0))
 [1]   1  77  82  97 126 150 214 267 278 416 522 617 621 701 714 810 822 858 859
[20] 876 886 ....